# How to disable responsive behavior in dnn7

Tags: responsive-design, dotnetnuke

I have problem in DNN7, I want to responsive behavior be disabled. how can I do it?
I tried some solutions but does not works:

```html
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Kindest Regards
seyed

Comment: here is my website address, [link](http://rositagift.com) there is something wrong about responsive behavior and it causes bad looking in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you change Skins in DNN to a non-bootstrap skin.